# type hinting and the reason(s) behind their limitations

Tags: php, types, type-hinting

Are `object` and `array` really the only types allowed for type hinting?

Plus, they state in documentation that standard types `string` and `int` cannot be type hinted also.

And that makes me more curious. What is the reason behind only allowing two type hints and the dropping of standard ones?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can also a class as a type.

Comment: You can also use an interface as a type.

Comment: They fall in the category of `object` anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP 5.3 currently supports only `array` and `ClassName` typehints.
The upcoming PHP 5.4 version will also support `callable` typehints.

The reason why scalar typehints are currently not supported is that their behavior in a weakly typed language is unclear:

- Should an error be thrown, even if it's just the difference between `1` and `'1'`? -> Against PHP spirit
- Should normal PHP casts be applied? In that case `'hallo'` would give `0` for an `int` typehint -> Unintuitive
- Should some more strict casting rules apply?

That's the reason why the scalar typehint implementation was backed out of PHP 5.4 - there was no consensus on this question.

Comment: Ah, and that makes me think that PHP was somewhat experimental at start, and as it grows, it just expands upon itself. Any reference on *weakly typed language*?

Comment: @Tom http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_typing It means that PHP does implicit type casts. E.g. you can write `echo $int;` instead of doing an explicit `echo (string) $int;`

Comment: That means, that there is no way to enforce starters/experimenters/wanderers to use my application properly when writing low-level stuff?

Comment: You can only add `@param` annotations to help people use your APIs.

Comment: You could program defensively, but it's not recommended in APIs. It should be up to the developers to learn hwo to use them properly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, only array and object are the types allowed for type hinting.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

See the last line:

Type Hints can only be of the object and array (since PHP 5.1) type. Traditional type hinting with int and string isn't supported.